# How to attach tesseract sources in CLion?

Tags: clion

I'm trying to step into tesseract library function and I get "No implementations found" error message. Fair enough - I haven't shown Lion where the source code is located because I can't find such an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer - some goo soul has created a CMake Tesseract OCR project at https://github.com/aspotashev/tesseract-ocr-cmake